# Best way to construct a regexp matching the first item in Racket's sexp?

Tags: regex, scheme, racket, syntax-highlighting

I'm building a Racket (a lisp dialect) syntax highlighting plugin for VSCode. I've already got the regexps for most of the atoms (strings, numbers, keywords...) and also for comments. Now I'm trying to highlight sexps: that is, lists, whose first item is a function and the other items are one of the atoms I meantion earlier.

Example:

```lisp
(print "this" "and this" (string-append "and" " " "this"))
```

Now, `print` and `string-append` should be highlighted/scoped as function-call. How do I go about this?

For simplicity, let's assume `\w-_` are the only allowed characters in a function name. Then if I do something like:

```
(?x)  (?<=\() (?: \s*) ([\w-_]+)
```

with group 1 being the function name, the regexp will break if a comment (or a newline) is inserted between the leading parenthesis and the function name.

This will not work

```c
( ;#(commented out sexp) print "this")
```

Is there any workaround which would allow me to specify "the first non-comment thing match is the name of the function"? (and maybe also how would you approach the syntax-highlighting in general?)

Comment: You shouldn't use regular expressions for this. Regular expressions work well for things that don't have to "count" open and close delimiters. For anything that _would_ have to count open-parens and close-parens, you should use a Context-Free Grammar, not a regular expression.

Comment: However, for the purposes of syntax-highlighting, do you really need to highlight, for example the `add1` in `(add1 5)` differently from the `add1` in `(map add1 (list 6 7 8))`?

Comment: @AlexKnauth I'm not a regexp master, so I figured I'll try to ask somebody if it really isn't possible. Of course, now there's the question that you pose. I'll probably forgo the syntax highlighting of the first symbol, if it really isn't possible to do right 100% of the time.